# i created a SP with a return value but after execution it is showing 0 as return value

Tags: mysql

```
DROP PROCEDURE `take_id`; 
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `take_id`(IN `name` VARCHAR(50), IN `mslno` INT(11), OUT      `par` INT) NOT DETERMINISTIC CONTAINS SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE par INT(10) DEFAULT 0; 
    SELECT id from s_menu where name='FEES' INTO par; 
    SELECT par ; 
]   Insert Into s_menu(name,mslno,parentid) values(name,mslno,par); 
END
```

Comment: I assume the ] is a typo? AND you should not give parameters the same name as varaibles AND did you set delimiters (I don't see evidence of such)

Comment: You cannot use declared variables in SELECT .. INTO. Use local variables.

Comment: @Akina - yes you can

Comment: @P.Salmon No. Or at least OP must alter defined variable name.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
PROCEDURE `take_id` ( IN name VARCHAR(50), 
                      IN mslno INT(11), 
                      OUT par INT ) 
NOT DETERMINISTIC 
CONTAINS SQL 
SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
BEGIN 
    SELECT id INTO @par 
        FROM s_menu where name='FEES'; 
    INSERT INTO s_menu (name, mslno, parentid) 
        VALUES (name, mslno, @par); 
    SET par:= @par;
END
```

Or directly

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
PROCEDURE `take_id` ( IN name VARCHAR(50), 
                      IN mslno INT(11), 
                      OUT par INT ) 
NOT DETERMINISTIC 
CONTAINS SQL 
SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
BEGIN 
    SELECT id INTO par 
        FROM s_menu where name='FEES'; 
    INSERT INTO s_menu (name, mslno, parentid) 
        VALUES (name, mslno, par); 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
+----+----------+
| id | username |
+----+----------+
|  1 | aaa      |
|  2 | Jane     |
|  3 | Ali      |
+----+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

You should not use the same name for parameters, declared variables and column names so:-

```
DROP PROCEDURE if exists p;
delimiter $$ 
CREATE PROCEDURE p(IN `name` VARCHAR(50), IN `mslno` INT(11), OUT      `outpar` INT) 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE par INT(10) DEFAULT 0; 
    SELECT id from users where username = name INTO par; 
    set outpar =  par ; 
    #Insert Into s_menu(name,mslno,parentid) values(name,mslno,par); 
END $$
delimiter ;

call p('aaa',1,@outpar);
```

the procedure will return the result to par which then sets oupar will be returned to the user defined variable @outpar in the call statement which you can then select

```
select @outpar;
+---------+
| @outpar |
+---------+
|       1 |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

You could simplify this by simply selecting into the paramter outpar

```
CREATE PROCEDURE p(IN `name` VARCHAR(50), IN `mslno` INT(11), OUT      `outpar` INT) 
BEGIN 
    #DECLARE par INT(10) DEFAULT 0; 
    SELECT id from users where username = name INTO outpar; 
    #set outpar =  par ; 
    #Insert Into s_menu(name,mslno,parentid) values(name,mslno,par); 
END $$
```

Comment: thanks to all, but still my problem is not solved i have to fetch id from users table which should reflect in outpar after execution..

Comment: Not with you , both queries allow you to get the user id after the CALL and the first query will allow to insert ..values(..par). Can you expand on what your process is, perhaps you required a function rather than a procedure?